# Automation of Twinfield add in execution in Excel preferably using Python libraries

Tags: python-3.x, excel-addins, pyautogui, excel-automation, twinfield

I have been trying to automate the process of executing the "Twinfield Analysis" add-in in Excel for quite some time. The challenge I face is that this add-in is needed to be clicked and login details need to be entered every time I reopen the excel so that the data is refreshed with the latest data

I have tried doing automated refresh but that does not solve the purpose. Has anyone tried doing this with Python libraries like pyautoGUI and any other libraries? Since the requirement is a bit critical any quick help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks!!
[XL screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nPlZ4.png)

Comment: Hi there, what have you tried so far using Python?

Comment: I was experimenting with the following code, which I got from Stackoverflow but I don't think this works. 
As per the requirement, the complete step needs to be automated. from clickin on  "Twinfield Analysis" till we get the data in the xl
xlsx_file = 'Path of the file/Twinfield-Analysis.xlsx'
xl = win32com.client.DispatchEx("Excel.Application")
wb = xl.workbooks.open(xlsx_file)
xl.DisplayAlerts = False 
xl.Visible = True
wb.RefreshAll()
wb.Close(True)
xl.Quit()
del xl